# Upload Image to Facebook from phone via share dialog using JS SDK

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating an app using Cordova and the Facebook plugin, which means I have the functionality of the Javascript SDK. How can I upload an image using the share dialog. I  can share texts or already uploaded images via links. **But is it possible to upload images via the share dialog?**

I can upload images using the Graph API, but it has the disadvantages that I have to ask for permission to post on the timeline upfront, which is a bad user experience in my opinion.

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use facebook plugin for cordova which covers all of your needs.You can download from  (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.ccsoft.plugin.cordovafacebook) .It needs Android facebook SDK,download from  (http://developers.facebook.com/android/).
Here is the share function form this plugin that covers your need(I suppose).
    function share() {

```
       openFB.api({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/me/feed',
            params: {
                message:"Facebook ApI test",
                 link: 'http://www.example.com/loc8',
                 name:'Facebook Api Test ',
                //image that share in posted in user timeline
                 picture:'http://www.example.com/Test.png'
            },
            success: function() {

                alert('Image Successfully shared in facebook');
            },
            error: errorHandler});
    }
```

Also you can pass the image as argument like this

```
function share(image){
   //do the facebook share stuff

}
```

Comment: A very late thank you :) My problem is that the image is on the phone and not yet uploaded. I guess I have to use facebook's staging service, but I dont really know how to. For now I am continuing using a http-post method to upload pictues to facebook. But that is not as nice as the share dialog...

Comment: @sebvst You can upload your image to your server and pass the url of the image saved in your server as the **picture** parameter.